# Can't make, says Kernel source is missing

Tags: software-installation, kernel, source

I'm trying to follow the instructions here

http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FOP/Installing+FreePBX+13+on+Ubuntu+Server+14.04.2+LTS

to install FreePBX/Asterisk on my Ubuntu server. When I try to Make DAHDI, it gives me the error that:

```
You do not appear to have the sources for the 3.19.0-28-generic kernel installed.
```

I tried to follow all instructions for installing my source, but I'm still getting this error. When I run `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` I have noticed that it says

```
Picking 'linux-lts-vivid' as source package instead of 'linux-image-3.19.0-28-generic'"
```

so I'm wondering if that's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need the headers, So try:

1. Update package list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install last kernel with its headers (It seems you have vivid kernel), So run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
   ```